# Can i make the UISearch disappear till i click a button?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I’m using the search button in swift. I have a navigation bar at the top and i have a navigation bar button at in the navigation bar. I want when i click that button the `UISearch` thing covers the `navigation bar` and shows the `search`. I added the search to the navigation bar how do i make is not visible?

```
@IBOutlet var search: UISearchBar!
```

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the navigationItem.titleView correctly. You're setting the titleView to nil

Comment: add searchbar in a view , set that view as title view , searchbar.hiden= YES , at start and set to NO on click .